# Compiler ignores if else

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, c++11, g++

I have a function like this

```
template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
void input(Arg &arg, Args&... args) {
```

In there I have an if that checks if arg is an array or not(I handle arrays differently). I then try to access an index of the array but I get `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer`. This doesn't happen if I don't mix arrays and normal variables. What should I do?

Comment: If the `if` statement is the problem, why are you only showing us code that's 6 lines before that `if` ?

Comment: You could start by including the code you're asking about instead of describing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I think you will need to provide more code to show what you are dealing with.  Please research how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) and then upgrade your question to provide one.  In this context, it should be the minimal code and an invocation that does compile and an invocation that does not compile, along with the exact error message.

Comment: Make some edits to the question and it'll be up and running again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply overload the function to take a regular type and an array type, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    std::cout<<"Regular version !\n";
}

template <typename T>
void f(T t[])
{
    std::cout<<"Array version !\n";
}

int main() 
{
    f(2); // Prints "Regular version !"
    int k[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    f(k); // Prints "Array version !"
}
```

[**Working example**](http://ideone.com/pTwIT3)

Comment: `T t[]` as a parameter is ***not*** an array type! It is transformed into a pointer `T* t`! To properly take array arguments, you need a size and then form a reference to an array: `template<class T, size_t N> void f(T (&t)[N])`.

Comment: The array decays to a pointer after function resolution occurs, therefor it doesn't affect this

Comment: No it doesn't. The function *itself* actually looks like this to the compiler: `template<class T> void f(T* t)`.